# Form validation with spring mvc annotation

Tags: spring-mvc, error-handling, controller

I got some trouble to get spring validation based on annotation form works.

i added this to my spring-servlet.xml

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.it.controller" />`
(package containing all my controller)

and

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.it.form" />` 
(package containing all my form classes)

class email in package com.it.form :

```
public class email {
@NotEmpty
@Email
private String email;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public email() {
    email = "";
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

Form :

```
<body>
<form:form method="post" action="" commandName='email'>
    <div class="requestEmail">
        <form:label path="email">Entrez votre email:</form:label>
        <form:input path="email" />
        <form:errors path="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="VALIDER" />
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Controller :

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class passwordController {

/*
 * ##########################################################
 * 
 * Print & valid form Email
 * 
 * ##########################################################
 */

@RequestMapping(value = "/passwordChange.mvc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(final ModelMap model) {

    email email= new email();
    model.addAttribute("email", email);
    return "passwordChangeRequestEmail"; // jsp form 
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/passwordChange.mvc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(final ModelMap model,
        @ModelAttribute("email") @Valid final email email,
        final BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "error";
    }
    return "success";
}
```

}

it seems when i submit my form i am always redirect to /success page, even if i leave email input blank...

Dunno if i missed something
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Presumably you have the Hibernate validator dependency `hibernate-validator` for processing the JSR303 annotations?

Comment: Yes. i found the solution, i was not include <mvc:annotation driven /> .. :( i thought <context:component-scan base-package="com.it.controller" /> was enough..

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

to your servlet context file and to import a validator like Hibernate Validator in your classpath.